# Local subscriptions error while connecting to remote publisher

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication, database-replication, merge-replication

I am new with merge replication so non sense can be expected,

What i did.
1) New Local publication done is on remote server.

When i am trying to do local subscription with remote server for selection of publication server, in server name i used remote server ip 
103.247.99.75,1232  with login sa and password something. It gives error

```
  SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server. Connections through a server alias, IP address, or any other alternate name are not supported. Specify the actual server name, 'WIN-281IHETPBD4'. (Replication.Utilities)
```

Connection to remote server with above credentials are working using sql management studio.

Someone told me you need to update host file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`. So i added entry like `103.247.99.75,1232    WIN-281IHETPBD4` in hosts file. I thought i m done with fix but again i got the same error

Comment: Why negative vote???

Answer (score 0):

Replication requires the actual server name when making connections.  Try adding the local subscription with a server name, instead of an ip address.